# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have problem in relation

```
// Ticket Model 
<?php

class Ticket extends Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'tickets';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('client_id','event_id');

    public function events(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Events'); // Not Working
    }

    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Events'); // this working
    }

}

-------------------------
//Events Model

class Events extends Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'events';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('name','area','map1','map2','photo','date','time');

    public function ticket(){
        return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
    }

}
```

in tickets model ---> function (events) not working but (client) working when I use

```
$ticket = Ticket::find(1);
return $ticket->events->name; // this not working
```

but when I use client

```
$ticket = Ticket::find(1);
return $ticket->client->name;  // This Working Fine
```

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 0):

If those 2 functions has the same content (as you showed) result should be exactly the same. `events` seems not to be used to any other function or properties.

Make sure you use exactly same id (in this case `1` as `find` argument both for `events` and `client`

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

IF you have defined:

```
public function events(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Events'); // this working
}
```

you  should probably try to define it this way:

```
public function events(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Events','event_id'); 
}
```

You should also consider naming or model objects in singular (not class `Events` but class `Event`).

Comment: public function events(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Events'); // Not Working
    }

    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('client'); // this working
    }